# maven-replacer-plugin and windows paths

Tags: java, windows, maven, maven-replacer-plugin

I'm trying to replace a hardcoded linux path in an xml file with the maven build directory so that i can test on windows but when i use variable substitution with the maven-replacer-plugin the windows back slash path separators get removed. Is there a way to work around this?

For example:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>replace</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <filesToInclude>my_file</filesToInclude>
        <escape>true</escape>
        <replacements>
          <replacement>
            <token>/path/to/replace</token> 
            <value>${project.build.directory}</value>
          </replacement>
        </replacements>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The result is that i get a replaced value of something like "C:UsersPathNoSeparators"

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `backslash` in the replacement string maybe causing it to treat it as an escape character as the replacement is done using the Regex.

try adding the regex property to false.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>replace</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <filesToInclude>my_file</filesToInclude>
    <escape>true</escape>
    <regex>false</regex>
    <replacements>
      <replacement>
        <token>/path/to/replace</token> 
        <value>${project.build.directory}</value>
      </replacement>
    </replacements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

note the `<regex>false</regex>` configuration property.

Answer (score 1):

The regex parameter is used for token match and have no impact on the value. There is a problem in the maven google replacer plugin.

To pass through that issue, you can retreat the project.build.directory value with the build-helper-maven-plugin before passing it to the maven google replacer plugin.

This is a coding solution :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>regex-property</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <name>cheminCible</name>
              <value>${project.build.directory}</value>
              <regex>\\</regex>
              <replacement>/</replacement>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>replace</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <filesToInclude>my_file</filesToInclude>
    <escape>true</escape>
    <replacements>
      <replacement>
        <token>/path/to/replace</token> 
        <value>cheminCible</value>
      </replacement>
    </replacements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```